# QGLWidget not working correctly under Mac OS X Lion

Tags: qt, qglwidget

As you see -- I have no idea why it's not working at all.

When the program run, it will look like this:[image: broken display]

I'm using qt4-mac(v4.8.2) from macports. It seems that the package was pre-compiled.

And here's the source:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>

#include "GLPlayerWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     GLPlayerWindow window;
     window.show();
     window.resize(800, 600);

     return app.exec();
}
```

GLPlayerWindow.hpp:

```
#ifndef __GLPLAYERWINDOW__HPP__DEFINED__
#define __GLPLAYERWINDOW__HPP__DEFINED__

#include <string>

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QTimer>

#include <SimpleAV_SDL.h>

class GLPlayerWindow : public QGLWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     GLPlayerWindow(QWidget *parent = NULL);
     ~GLPlayerWindow();

protected slots:
     void paintGL();

protected:
     void initializeGL();
     void resizeGL(int w, int h);
     void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};

#endif
```

GLPlayerWindow.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GLPlayerWindow.hpp"
#include <GL/glu.h>

GLPlayerWindow::GLPlayerWindow(QWidget *parent)
     : QGLWidget(parent) {
     setMouseTracking(true);
}

GLPlayerWindow::~GLPlayerWindow() {
}

void GLPlayerWindow::initializeGL() {
     glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     glEnable(GL_BLEND);
     glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
     glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0);
}

void GLPlayerWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
     glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluOrtho2D(0, w, 0, h); // set origin to top left corner
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();
}

void GLPlayerWindow::paintGL() {
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     return;
}

void GLPlayerWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
}
```

And the .pro file:

```
QT += opengl
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libavcodec libavformat libavutil libswscale SimpleAV_SDL sdl SDL_mixer gl glu

# LIBS += `pkg-config --libs SimpleAV_SDL SDL_mixer sdl`
# CFLAGS += -g -O2 -Wall -W `pkg-config --cflags SimpleAV_SDL SDL_mixer sdl`
CFLAGS += -g -O2 -Wall -W

# Input
HEADERS += GLPlayerWindow.hpp
SOURCES += GLPlayerWindow.cpp main.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys if you are facing the same issue *under Mac*, try to link the GL implementation under /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/ . See this post for detail: [Why glOrtho() works under Mac but gluOrtho2D() doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315126/why-glortho-works-under-mac-but-gluortho2d-doesnt/)